# Non-conservative electric fields

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, potential, conservative-field

Is the electric field produced by uniformly moving charges non-conservative? And if it is, then why?

Comment: See the answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/251788/9887)

Answer (score 2):

For a field to be conservative, you need $\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = 0$. See in my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/426355/how-do-i-show-that-e-equiv-frac12-m-dotx2-ux-is-constant-for-a-classi/426365#426365) how this relates to *converservation* of energy and path indepenedence.

The third Maxwell equation (Faraday's law + Lenz's law) states:

$$ \nabla \times \mathbf{E} = -\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t} \neq 0. $$

This is your first inkling that, when you have moving charges and hence electro*dyanmics* (as opposed to electro*statics*, where $\partial/\partial t = 0$) entails a non-conservative electric field.

If you don't want to use Maxwell's equation, you can also start from the general expression for the electric field $$ \mathbf{E} = -\nabla\phi -  \frac{\partial\mathbf{A}}{\partial t},$$

and left multiply by $\nabla \times$, obtaining the same result.

---

Now, to be a bit more pedantic. 
 In order to have $\nabla\times\mathbf{E} = 0$ from the equation above, you require:

- either $\partial/\partial t = 0$, i.e. electrostatics
- or $\mathbf{B}  = 0$
- or  both.

This is why, I am assuming, knzhou asked you about accelerating charges in the comment. 
 Because, what if you have a moving charge which is **not** generating a magnetic field? Then $\partial/\partial t \neq 0$ but $\mathbf{B} = 0$, which guarantees an overall $\nabla\times\mathbf{E} = 0.$

However, you already know that a charge moving at constant velocity is basically a current (if you consider a very small length element $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$), which you know creates a magnetic field $\mathbf{B} \neq 0$.

Indeed, the full expression for the electric and magnetic fields is given [here](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath576/kmath576.htm), and an example of the expression is given in the answer linked by Alfred Centauri.

---

Let me add a final remark.

What if you travelling in a frame of reference that moves at the same speed as a constant-velocity moving charge? Then you would see the charge as stationary, with both $\mathbf{B} = 0$ (ignoring spin) and $\partial/\partial t = 0$. 
 This is because magnetic field naturally come out of electrostatics + special relativity, i.e. they are electric fields seen in a different reference frame. (magnetic fields from magnets are still relativistic because they come from spin, which is a "relativistic" effect in the sense that it comes from the Dirac equation).